# create a Circular progressbar with circular background

Tags: android, xml, android-progressbar

[see this Image](http://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/12/catnames.gif)

I want to create a new swipe down refresh progress bar. A circle and a arrow rotating inside that like **Gmail** app do. The sample image is shown above.

Comment: Hi dude, I just answered the question below. Edit and improve your question with the term "swipe down refresh", then only the question get attention.

Comment: I think this question is not there in stackoverflow , so if the question is well received it will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is called **swipe down refresh**, To implement this you have to use **android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout**.

The first thing we need to do is add the support library to our application’s build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

Then we have to create a layout like this.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

You can find a great tutorial [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/) with the code.